# how can i add a drop-down button to this flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:api_app/screens/home.dart';

import 'package:api_app/utils/api_endpoints.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class RegisterationController extends GetxController {

  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();

  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();

  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  final Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  Future<void> registerWithEmail() async {

    try {

      var headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};

      var url = Uri.parse(

          ApiEndPoints.baseUrl + ApiEndPoints.authEndpoints.registerEmail);

      Map body = {

        'name': nameController.text,

        'email': emailController.text.trim(),

        'password': passwordController.text

      };

      http.Response response =

          await http.post(url, body: jsonEncode(body), headers: headers);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {

        final json = jsonDecode(response.body);

        if (json['code'] == 0) {

          var token = json['data']['Token'];

          print(token);

          final SharedPreferences? prefs = await _prefs;

          await prefs?.setString('token', token);

          nameController.clear();

          emailController.clear();

          passwordController.clear();

          Get.off(HomeScreen());

        } else {

          throw jsonDecode(response.body)["message"] ?? "Unknown Error Occured";

        }

      } else {

        throw jsonDecode(response.body)["Message"] ?? "Unknown Error Occured";

      }

    } catch (e) {

      Get.back();

      showDialog(

          context: Get.context!,

          builder: (context) {

            return SimpleDialog(

              title: Text('Error'),

              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),

              children: [Text(e.toString())],

            );

          });

    }

  }

}
```

Registration Controller ☝️

login Controller

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:api_app/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:api_app/utils/api_endpoints.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class LoginController extends GetxController {
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  Future<void> loginWithEmail() async {
    var headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
    try {
      var url = Uri.parse(
          ApiEndPoints.baseUrl + ApiEndPoints.authEndpoints.loginEmail);
      Map body = {
        'email': emailController.text.trim(),
        'password': passwordController.text
      };
      http.Response response =
          await http.post(url, body: jsonEncode(body), headers: headers);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final json = jsonDecode(response.body);
        if (json['code'] == 0) {
          var token = json['data']['Token'];
          final SharedPreferences? prefs = await _prefs;
          await prefs?.setString('token', token);

          emailController.clear();
          passwordController.clear();
          Get.off(HomeScreen());
        } else if (json['code'] == 1) {
          throw jsonDecode(response.body)['message'];
        }
      } else {
        throw jsonDecode(response.body)["Message"] ?? "Unknown Error Occured";
      }
    } catch (error) {
      Get.back();
      showDialog(
          context: Get.context!,
          builder: (context) {
            return SimpleDialog(
              title: Text('Error'),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              children: [Text(error.toString())],
            );
          });
    }
  }
}
```

auth screen

```
import 'package:api_app/controllers/login_controller.dart';
import 'package:api_app/controllers/registeration_controller.dart';
import 'package:api_app/screens/auth/widgets/input_fields.dart';
import 'package:api_app/screens/auth/widgets/submit_button.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class AuthScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<AuthScreen> createState() => _AuthScreenState();
}

class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen> {
  RegisterationController registerationController =
      Get.put(RegisterationController());

  LoginController loginController = Get.put(LoginController());

  var isLogin = false.obs;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(36),
          child: Center(
            child: Obx(
              () => Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text(
                        'WELCOME',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 30,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        MaterialButton(
                          color: !isLogin.value ? Colors.white : Colors.amber,
                          onPressed: () {
                            isLogin.value = false;
                          },
                          child: Text('Register'),
                        ),
                        MaterialButton(
                          color: isLogin.value ? Colors.white : Colors.amber,
                          onPressed: () {
                            isLogin.value = true;
                          },
                          child: Text('Login'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 80,
                    ),
                    isLogin.value ? loginWidget() : registerWidget()
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget registerWidget() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        InputTextFieldWidget(registerationController.nameController, 'name'),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        InputTextFieldWidget(
            registerationController.emailController, 'email address'),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        InputTextFieldWidget(
            registerationController.passwordController, 'password'),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        SubmitButton(
          onPressed: () => registerationController.registerWithEmail(),
          title: 'Register',
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget loginWidget() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        InputTextFieldWidget(loginController.emailController, 'email address'),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        InputTextFieldWidget(loginController.passwordController, 'password'),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        SubmitButton(
          onPressed: () => loginController.loginWithEmail(),
          title: 'Login',
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

home page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'auth/auth_screen.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(actions: [
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final SharedPreferences? prefs = await _prefs;
              prefs?.clear();
              Get.offAll(AuthScreen());
            },
            child: Text(
              'logout',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ))
      ]),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Welcome home'),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  final SharedPreferences? prefs = await _prefs;
                  print(prefs?.get('token'));
                },
                child: Text('print token'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

there are two another files that contains input fields and submit button widgets

please help me to add a drop-down button to the flutter app shown above the fictions and widgets settings are in different files so i am not able to find a way

Comment: Hi, it's to much code for someone to analyze, if you could exclude code that's not related to your question

Comment: you can ignore the login Controller and home page because i need the drop-down in registration page so.. and registration Controller is contained with data storing ect... and auth screen have the text fields and button functions are located

Comment: then simplify the code to the absolute minimum

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have putted so much codes, so I didn't catch what exactly you want, but if you meant "How can make a dropDownButton in flutter?" I will add a simple code from one of my projects, and I hope it will give you an idea..

```
DropdownButtonFormField(
                          focusColor: AppColors.whiteColor,
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_down_rounded),
                          decoration: inputDecoration(),
                          value: controller.vilValue,
                          items: controller.vilNames
                              .map(
                                (item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: item,
                              child: Center(
                                child: titleText(
                                  text: item,
                                  size: Dimensions.font16,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                              .toList(),
                          onChanged: controller.changeVillageValue,
                        ),
```